# can correlation coefficient be considered a modeling tool?

Tags: regression, correlation, model

I have the idea that the objective of a model is to summarize a data set in some numbers that can explain the whole. For example a regression line returns numbers that describe possible relations of the dependent and independent variables.

My question is if you think correlation can be thought as a statistical model? or what else should be needed in order to say it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, a model is thought of an inferential tool rather than a descriptive one. That is, a model estimates unseen information rather than just summarizing what you already know. Still, computing a Pearson correlation can readily be construed as a simple modeling exercise. The Pearson correlation is just a normalized version of the coefficient from a [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) model. So while we wouldn't call the Pearson correlation itself a "model"—we'd call it as a "statistic", "estimate", "parameter", "statistical functional", or "population quantity", depending on how it's used—it's closely related to a model.